# Kotlin Immediate execute postDelayed

Tags: kotlin, handler, looper

On specific events I want to stop a handler. I want a target to fade after several seconds. I want to interrupt and immediately fade (or extend time before fading how can I do this?  What is the new best practice for accomplishing this? Here is existing code:

```
    private fun startTargetFade(target: Target, delayMs: Long = 2000) {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            target.isVisible = false
            viewModel.remove(target)
        }, delayMs)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CountDownTimer not a looper. I created a class that contains both the CountDownTimer and Target. When I want to do something to the Target based on the CountDownTimer, I find the instance containing the timer, I know its sibling, the Target is the object I need to act on.

```
val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(wadeTime, 1000) {
                        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
                        override fun onFinish() {}
```

if I want to end early is call:

```
countDownTimer.cancel()
```